# pagination sql/php error when delete comments

Tags: php, sql, ajax, pagination

I have a comment system in my website.
The problem occurs if "A" delete a comment when "B" is using pagination.

ajax sends 1, 2, 3, 4... to php, depends on page.

php receive ajax:

```
$pagecont = ($pagecont*7);
```

and after that

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM comments where post='$id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $pagecont,7)sub ORDER BY id ASC");
```

so, if "B" is in page 1 and "A" delete comments in the same page, when "B" click to page 2, my website will skip some of them.

What could I do to prevent my website to skip comments in this case?